# My image doesn't get centered horizontally and it also overflows the container of bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As far as I know, the Bootstrap class container sets the width of the content to max 1140px.

Here's how my page is looking:
[image: photo]

the left-sided menu is placed properly (in my mind it makes sense to position it using position: absolute if the whole website will have 1140px width) but the other content should not overflow this 1140px container.

Now I want to place that image just above the text and I'm not able to do it. (tried it with margin-left: auto + margin-right: auto + display:block / text-align: center)

Here's the snippet:

```js
var enunt = document.querySelector(".enunt");
var rezolvare = document.querySelector(".rezolvare");
var explicatie = document.querySelector(".explicatie");
var complexitate = document.querySelector(".complexitate");
var executie = document.querySelector(".executie");

var enuntText = document.querySelector(".enunt-BST");
var rezolvareText = document.querySelector(".rezolvare-BST");
var explicatieText = document.querySelector(".explicare-BST");
var complexitateText = document.querySelector(".complexitate-BST");
var executieText = document.querySelector(".executie-BST");

enunt.addEventListener("click", function() {
    enuntText.style.display = "block";
    rezolvareText.style.display = "none";
    explicatieText.style.display = "none";
    complexitateText.style.display = "none";
    executieText.style.display = "none";
});

rezolvare.addEventListener("click", function() {
    enuntText.style.display = "none";
    rezolvareText.style.display = "block";
    explicatieText.style.display = "none";
    complexitateText.style.display = "none";
    executieText.style.display = "none";
});

explicatie.addEventListener("click", function() {
    enuntText.style.display = "none";
    rezolvareText.style.display = "none";
    explicatieText.style.display = "block";
    complexitateText.style.display = "none";
    executieText.style.display = "none";
});

complexitate.addEventListener("click", function() {
    enuntText.style.display = "none";
    rezolvareText.style.display = "none";
    explicatieText.style.display = "none";
    complexitateText.style.display = "block";
    executieText.style.display = "none";
});

executie.addEventListener("click", function() {
    enuntText.style.display = "none";
    rezolvareText.style.display = "none";
    explicatieText.style.display = "none";
    complexitateText.style.display = "none";
    executieText.style.display = "block";
});
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video, button {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

html {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 10px;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-color: #00000f;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    font-family: "Proxima Nova" !important;
    font-size: 10px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #00000f !important;
}

.navbar-custom {
    position: relative;
}

.abs-center-x {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.bg-transparent {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

.nav-color {
    color :#fff !important;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 5px;
}

.nav-color:hover {
    color: #77dff1 !important;
}

.nav-active {
    color: #77dff1 !important;
}

.display-custom {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #77dff1;
    font-size: 17.5rem !important;
    text-align: center;
}

.lead-custom {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 710px;
    line-height: 35px;
    color: #eeede7 !important;
}

/*Continut centru*/

#central {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova', sans-serif;
    display: table;
    width: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#intro-wrap {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 710px;
    width: 100%;
}

#intro {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #77dff1 !important;
    font-size: 17.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.intro {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 710px;
    line-height: 35px;
    color: #eeede7 !important;
}

#hr {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

hr {
    border-color: #77dff1 !important;
    max-width: 90%;
}


.button-wrap {
    postion: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2.5rem;
}

.button-custom {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #77dff1;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.button-custom:hover {
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #00000f;
    background: #77dff1;
}

/* probleme DEI */

.list-item-custom {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #77dff1;
    color: #77dff1;
    padding: 2rem 4rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.7rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.list-item-custom:hover {
    background-color: #77dff1;
    color: #fff;
}

.col-sm-6 {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #77dff1;
    color: #77dff1;
    padding: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.col-hover:hover {
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #fff;
    background: #77dff1;
}

.col-custom {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.pre-scrollable {
    max-height: 700px !important;
    border: 1px solid #77dff1;
}

.lista-pasi-executie {
    list-style: decimal;
}

.fontawesome-custom {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    color: #77dff1;
    font-size: 20rem;
}

.autor-color {
    color: #77dff1;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.explicatie-rezolvare {
    color: #77dff1;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.lista-observatii {
    list-style: disc;
}

.lista-pasi-executie > li {
    margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Divide et Impera</title>
    <link href="../css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/fonts.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6612084f00.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" style="color: #fff !important"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
              <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-link nav-color" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-link nav-color" href="#">Introducere DEI</a>
                <a class="nav-link nav-color" href="#">DEI Iterativ</a>
                <a class="nav-link nav-color nav-active" href="#">Probleme DEI</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 1%; transform:translateY(-50%);">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom enunt">Enunt</li>
                    <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom rezolvare">Rezolvare + cod</li>
                    <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom explicatie">Explicatie rezolvare</li>
                    <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom complexitate">Complexitate</li>
                    <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom executie">Executie</li>
                  </ul>
          </div>
              <div class="enunt-BST">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-custom">
                    <i class="fas fa-clipboard fontawesome-custom"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div id="central">
                  <div class="col-custom">
                    <h1 class="display-3">Autor: <span class="autor-color">Mihai Vasile</span></h1>
                  </div>
                      <div class="col-custom">
                            Sa se demonstreze daca un arbore binar este de tipul BST (binary search tree)
                            <div class="observatie-BST">
                              <span style="font-weight: bold; color: #77dff1;">Observatie </span>- un BST are urmatoarele proprietati:
                            </div>
                            <ul class="lista-observatii">
                              <li>Orice subarbore din partea stanga al unui nod contine valori mai mici decat nodul “tata”</li>
                              <li>Orice subarbore din partea dreapta al unui nod contine valori mai mari decat nodul “tata”</li>
                              <li>Atat subarborele drept, cat si cel stang trebuie sa fie la randul lor BST</li>
                            </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="rezolvare-BST" style="display: none; color: #fff;">
                <div id="central">
                    <div class="col-custom">
                          <pre class="pre-scrollable" style="color: #fff; text-align: justify;">
                        #include "iostream"

                        using namespace std;
                        
                        //Un nod al unui arbore binar are drept componente id-ul sau,
                        //cat si pointeri catre "copilul" drept si cel stang.
                        
                        class node
                        {
                        public:
                            int data;
                            node* left;
                            node* right;
                        
                            // Allocam noului nod id-ul sau 
                            //si initializam pointeri catre stanga si dreapta cu NULL
                            node(int data)
                            {
                                this->data = data;
                                this->left = NULL;
                                this->right = NULL;
                            }
                        };
                        
                        int isBSTUtil(node* node, int min, int max);
                        
                        /* Functia principala ce verifica daca arborele binar
                        este de tip BST sau nu, utilizand o functie secundara numita
                        isBSTUtil */
                        int isBST(node* node)
                        {
                            return(isBSTUtil(node, INT_MIN, INT_MAX));
                        }
                        /* Intoarce adevarat daca arborele dat este de tip BST si
                        se respecta conditiile impuse in cerinta: 
                        id-ul sa fie >=min si <=max 
                        */
                        int isBSTUtil(node* node, int min, int max)
                        {
                            /* un nod NULL este de tip BST */
                            if (node == NULL)
                                return 1;
                        
                            /* fals daca id-ul nodului nu este cuprins intre min si max */
                            if (node->data < min || node->data > max)
                                return 0;
                        
                            /* Daca nodul curent respecta conditia BST, se verifica recursiv subarbori acestuia,
                            modificand corespunzator min si max */
                            return
                                isBSTUtil(node->left, min, node->data - 1) && // Id-urile nu trebuie sa se repete  
                                isBSTUtil(node->right, node->data + 1, max); // Id-urile nu trebuie sa se repete
                        }
                        
                        
                        int main()
                        {
                            node* root = new node(4);
                            root->left = new node(2);
                            root->right = new node(5);
                            root->left->left = new node(1);
                            root->left->right = new node(3);
                        
                            if (isBST(root))
                                cout << "Este BST";
                            else
                                cout << "Nu este BST";
                        
                            return 0;
                        }
                          </pre>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="explicare-BST" style="display: none; color: #fff;">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-custom">
                  <i class="far fa-lightbulb fontawesome-custom"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="central">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-custom" style="text-align: left;">
                    <span class="explicatie-rezolvare">Explicatie rezolvare:</span>  
    Problema are la baza verificarea daca id-urile unice ale unor noduri dintr-un arbore respecta conditiile specifice unui arbore BST.
    Incepem prin a ne declara arborele, acesta fiind o clasa ce contine: id-ul, cat si pointeri catre „fii” (subarborii) sai: stang si drept.
    Se apeleaza functia ce verifica daca arborele este BST sau nu, aceasta efectuand urmatoarele operatii:
    <ol class="lista-pasi-executie">
      <li>Se seteaza initial limitele intre care trebuie sa se situeze nodurile min si max drept limitele tipului de data INT</li>
      <li>Verifica daca nodul dat este NULL, caz in care returnaza adevarat (un nod gol este de tip BST deoarece nu influenteaza min si max si nu are un id asociat)</li>
      <li>Se verifica daca id-ul nodului este cuprins in intervalul [min,max].</li>
      <li>In caz negativ, functia returneaza 0;</li>
      <li>In caz afirmativ, se apeleaza recursiv functia mai intai pe partea stanga a arborelui, dupa care pe partea dreapta, modificand min si max corespunzator directiei in care o luam</li>
    </ol>  
                    </div>
                </div>   
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="complexitate-BST" style="display: none; color: #fff;">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-custom">
                  <img src="https://imgur.com/a/6lS74SW" style="text-align: center;"><br>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="central">              
                <div class="col-custom">
                        Complexitate: O(n) <br>
                        Demonstratie complexitate: <br>
                        Algoritmul prezentat mai sus verifica daca id-ul nodului curent se afla in intervalul [min,max]. In caz afirmativ, acesta se autoapeleaza si continua aceasta verificare a id-ului mai intai in subarborii stangi, dupa care cei drepti.
                        Astfel, pentru un arbore de marime n, sunt parcurse in mod recursiv toate cele n noduri, ceea ce da programului o complexitate medie de O(n).
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="executie-BST" style="display: none;">
              
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="../js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

How can I place that image just above the text? (click on "Complexitate" in the menu to see what the text & image)

Comment: Don't use position absolute for such a basic layout.

Comment: @cloned can you please help me fix it? I would've looked into it myself, but this project is for school and it has to be ready until 13th jan, and I'm afraid it won't be ready. If you do, can you also explain to me why is my approach wrong?

Comment: because positioning elements can give a lot of issues espacially for responsive designs. Besides it requires good calculations while such a basic layout is achieved the most easiest way with the use of flexbox and css-grid. Requires far less hard coding and can be adjust for mobile screens with the sue of media queries way easier.